# EntityFramework Core - Related Entities without specific foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext, ef-model-builder

thanks for taking the time to look over my question.

I am trying to get some data along with the related records from a database using a DbContext.
I already have an example of this setup for one of my relationships -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<FinancialTransaction>()
                .HasOne<LedgerEntry>(e => e.ledger_entry)
                .WithOne(t => t.financial_transaction)
                .HasForeignKey<LedgerEntry>(e => e.financial_transaction_id);
        }
```

However, I also have a table which has loose references to other records, using a combination of `source_id` and `source_type` columns. `Source_id` is the primary key of the other record, and `source_type` is the singular name of the other record type (such as "account", "user" etc.).

Is anyone aware of a way to set this up using `EntityFramework`, similar to my example above?
Any advice is appreciated and if you need any more information, please ask :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a one to one relationship? Can you post the entities with relevant properties?

Comment: It is a one to one relationship. After tinkering a bit more with this I'm not sure if it is possible as the second table does not have a column containing its Type. Still worth making sure though! Thanks